# Postfix tries to connect to the domain instead of the hostname

Tags: postfix

I have several problems with my Postfix configuration. Let's start by this one: in the Postfix logs, Postfix tries to connect (SMTP) to `example.org` instead of `mailer.example.org`. `example.org` is another computer.

Note: I replaced below `example.org` by a domain I own. DNS resolution for both `example.org` (a computer running a web server) and `mailer.example.org` (the computer running postfix) is correct.

The test trying to send an email:

```
ubuntu@mailer:~$ telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mailer.example.org ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo mailer.example.org
250-mailer.example.org
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
mail from: <root@example.org>
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: <foo@example.org>
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
asdfasdf
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 3AB5A41927
```

/var/log/mail.log:

```
Sep  6 20:10:15 mailer postfix/smtpd[2785]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep  6 20:10:23 mailer postfix/smtp[2779]: connect to example.org[54.229.20.238]:25: Connection timed out
Sep  6 20:10:23 mailer postfix/smtp[2779]: 253C641852: to=<foo@example.org>, relay=none, delay=1059, delays=1029/0.02/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to example.org[54.229.20.238]:25: Connection timed out)
Sep  6 20:10:40 mailer postfix/smtpd[2785]: 3AB5A41927: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Sep  6 20:10:48 mailer postfix/cleanup[2789]: 3AB5A41927: message-id=<20130906201040.3AB5A41927@mailer.example.org>
Sep  6 20:10:48 mailer postfix/qmgr[2776]: 3AB5A41927: from=<root@example.org>, size=422, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep  6 20:10:50 mailer postfix/smtpd[2785]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

postconf -n:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
local_recipient_maps =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination =
myhostname = mailer.example.org
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = $mydomain
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /mnt/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 51200000
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 5000
virtual_transport = virtual
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

Thanks in advance of any possible help. I'm blocked :(

Cheers,
Christophe

Comment: What do your DNS MX records look like for example.org? I believe if you don't have them set up at all, it defaults to the domain name.  You should at least have a MX record with mailer.example.org and an arbitrary weight (like 10). Also, if this box is to receive mail, example.org needs to either be in your virtual domains (which, since they are in mysql, are not visible here), or you need to put it in mydestination

Comment: @AndrewCho: well spotted: the DNS MX record was missing. What about adding this as an answer, that I'll accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from comment:

What do your DNS MX records look like for example.org? I believe if you don't have them set up at all, it defaults to the domain name. You should at least have a MX record with mailer.example.org and an arbitrary weight (like 10). Also, if this box is to receive mail, example.org needs to either be in your virtual domains (which, since they are in mysql, are not visible here), or you need to put it in mydestination.